# Scan text file into Matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a text file which I want to import into matlab. Here are the first 2 rows of the text file (tempfile.txt):

```
1,"4/26/2016","6:40:00 PM","111","0","13.45","NaN","ACTIVE","NaN",
2,"4/26/2016","6:40:30 PM","73","0","14.99","NaN","ACTIVE","NaN",
```

When I tried using textscan:

```
fid = fopen('tempfile.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%*d %s %s %s %*d %*d %*d %*s %*s', 'Delimiter', ',')
```

It only imports the first row of the text file. I have tried adding \n to the formatSpec but it still does not work. Please help!

Comment: why are you using the asterisk? are you after the field width?

Comment: I only require the date, time and the fourth (111 & 73) column field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that all of your fields are double quoted - i.e. They are strings, and you cannot parse them in as Floats/Doubles, instead parse them in as strings, and cast them to Doubles in Matlab:

```
data = textscan(fid, '%d %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s', 'Delimiter', ',')
```

works fine at parsing your data, then use `str2num` to convert your data back to numeric. Why do you have double quotes around everything?

=============EDIT============

Since you only want 3 fields, you should do something like:

```
 fid = fopen('abc1.txt');
 data = textscan(fid, '%*d %s %s %s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s', 'Delimiter', ',')
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot, you are my hero, as I have trying to figure importing data into matlab for the whole day. Anyway, I am not sure why there are double quotes, but as you suggested, str2num solves it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a comma separated values CSV file try this function instead:

```
M = csvread('tempfile.txt')
```

Comment: That's not possible as csvread requires all elements to be numeric (I think so), which my text file does not qualify